# Masscan output How can I grab just the ip:port and save to a file?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Im using "masscan -iL /home/iplist.txt -oL /home/result.txt --open --rate 10000 -p1-65535"

After masscan scanning ip ranges it outputs ip's in such awfull format. Can somebody help me changing the output format or change it using grep or awk command?

```
open tcp 3389 149.240.45.4 1607123941
open tcp 1256 149.240.0.137 1607123941
open tcp 3388 149.240.119.78 1607123941
open tcp 1221 149.240.248.56 1607123941
open tcp 1234 88.198.83.9 1607123941
```

And i want it look like

```
149.240.45.4:3389
149.240.0.137:1256
149.240.119.78:3388
149.240.248.56:1221
88.198.83.9:1234
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with awk:

```
$ awk '{print $4 ":" $3}' FILE
149.240.45.4:3389
149.240.0.137:1256
149.240.119.78:3388
149.240.248.56:1221
88.198.83.9:1234
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. Used `match` function to match regex for catching digits with ip as per shown samples.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]{4} ([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr," ")
  print arr[2]":"arr[1]
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `AWK`, let `file.txt` content be:

```
open tcp 3389 149.240.45.4 1607123941
open tcp 1256 149.240.0.137 1607123941
open tcp 3388 149.240.119.78 1607123941
open tcp 1221 149.240.248.56 1607123941
open tcp 1234 88.198.83.9 1607123941
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=":"}{print $4,$3}' file.txt
```

output

```
149.240.45.4:3389
149.240.0.137:1256
149.240.119.78:3388
149.240.248.56:1221
88.198.83.9:1234
```

Explanation: set output field separator to `:`, then just get needed fields.